# Weird issue using our application's API with VPN software

Tags: php, api, ssl, apache2, vpn

I have written a web application for a customer that has a **JavaScript frontend** and a **PHP backend** (API).

The customer's employees have to run a VPN software (called Pulse) when using the internet.

My (frontend and backend) applications run on `Apache2` and use a `Let's Encrypt` SSL certificate to serve HTTPS requests. So far, everything works perfectly fine on my test computers.

When testing the web application at my customer's computer with this VPN software, we ran into weird issues:

- Using Firefox, they cannot visit any HTTPS secured website. Firefox throws a certificate error. Looking into the certificate, it says: Issued by `Their Company` instead of `Let's Encrypt`. This is not really my issue, because it happens with all websites - but still very odd?
- Using Internet Explorer 11, there is no certificate error or warning whatsoever. But the web application behaves in a weird way. To be more specific, empty API responses of the backend do not come back (developer tools in IE11 says: "waiting for response"). The requests never seem to finish, even if the server is already finished with the reply.
- As soon as the server replies with a response that is not empty, IE11 doesn't seem to have a problem.
- Even more odd, this empty response issue only appears when running this VPN software. Without that software, all requests work fine.

Do you think this is an issue from my application or the VPN software?

Here is a sample request that will raise these weird issues. In IE11 in combination with this software, I will not get the response, otherwise I do.

**Request**

```
POST https://myapplication.com/api/login/ HTTP/1.1
Host: myapplication.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://myapplication.com/frontend/
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 66
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive

{"email":"myemail","password":"mypassword"}
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 12:28:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, session
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 20
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

Please note that I enabled CORS on the API webserver. But I can't imagine this is the issue here.